# After tvOS 10, can I use HomeKit framework to create server app on AppleTV to control third party accessory?

Tags: homekit, wwdc, ios-homekit

After this WWDC 2016, I am still not sure can I write server or server like App on Apple TV to manage all of my accessories.

I wanna create an app can do the job like my BOSCH security alarm control panel.

You know, there are lots of rules and relationships in a standard security control panel. The control panel will response any event based on a serial of comprehensive rules.

Is that possible to make Apple TV works like security alarm system?